# Should I try to reduce selected rows in the subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM qanda question
JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
AND answer.author_id = 29
AND question.amount IS NULL
AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
AND answer.id not in (
  select post_id
  from votes
  group by post_id
  having sum(value) < 0)
```

Currently that subquery selects 890 rows in reality. I can reduce it to just 43 rows by adding this *(the time frame constraint which is in the outer query)* also to the subquery:

```
. . . where  date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

And I can reduce it more *(to just 9 rows)* by adding this line on the `WHERE` clause of that subquery:

```
. . . and table_code = 15
```

Ok, Some programmers believe:

> Adding a where clause to the inner query would reduce the rows but would only remove rows that don't matter.

But I myself believe adding a `WHERE` clause for that inner query makes it more faster. Well I'm confuse, should I add those conditions on the `WHERE` clause of that inner query or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I think this would only be helpful if you were doing an `IN` test, since that can use an index on the outer table. WIth `NOT IN`, it has to do a full scan, so reducing the size of the subquery doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Also, reducing the size of the subquery in `NOT IN` means that **more** rows will match the `NOT IN` condition.

Comment: It seems like adding predicates in the subquery changes the set of post_id values returned, given that rows would be excluded, and the evaluation of the `sum(value)` could yield a different result.And that seems like it's going to influence the set of rows returned by the outer query. Yes, given a suitable index available, adding predicates to the subquery could potentially improve performance, but that's not necessarily going to be true all the time. What seems to be missing is a *specification* for what rows should be returned by the outer query.

Comment: @Barmar I read your second query several times but still I cannot understand what's your point. I just can understand you're agree with not adding a `WHERE` clause for that subquery, right?

Comment: @stack Yes, I don't think it will help in this case. And I suspect spencer7593 is right that it may change the semantics of the query.

Comment: I don't get how that should work. My expected result is `1052: Column 'date_time' in where clause is ambiguous`.

Comment: @stack overall, everyone's finding is correct the more conditions returns less rows and obvious faster when we are using that block in sub query. According my finding, in case of NOT IN  || IN it doesn't help because in both cases it needs to scan whole table. So you can write EXISTS or NOT EXISTS instead of IN or NOT IN.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That should be `answer.date_time`

Comment: @Barmar Can you **please** read the following answer and tell me your opinion about it?

Comment: @stack How did I become your personal answer-man? Based on the frequency of questions you post, it seems like you really need to get yourself an experienced SQL programmer.

Comment: @Barmar well sorry for pinging you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM qanda question
JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
AND answer.author_id = 29
AND question.amount IS NULL
AND answer.date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
AND 0 <= (
  select sum(value)
  from votes
  where post_id = answer.id
)
```

?

There are of course other ways.

However - your subquery is reading the entire `votes` table, while you only need those related to the authors answers. So you could limit the result set of your subquery using a join with the answers:

```
AND answer.id not in (
    select v.post_id
    from votes v
    join qanda a on a.id = v.post_id
    where a.author_id = 29
      and a.date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
      and a.related IS NOT NULL
    group by v.post_id
    having sum(v.value) < 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. Just why do you think this query is better than mine *(which is in the question)*?

Comment: Because your subquery is reading the entire votes table. While my correlated subquery is reading only related votes.

Comment: Your second query has this error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'a.post_id' in 'group statement' `

Comment: good .. but one thing, is your second query supposed to be as the subquery of your first query? Because it returns a `post_id`, not the number of answers that have zero or more upvote.

Comment: No.. second query is a replacement for your subquery.

Comment: well it doesn't make any sense. the first query returns this `count(1)`, but the second one returns this `v.post_id`, how can they be a replacement of each other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123029/discussion-between-paul-spiegel-and-stack).